# TCP network stream handling

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I serve various TCP clients asynchronously via their respective TCP sockets. Currently, I have 3 tasks running simultaneously:

1. Await data from the `NetworkStream` using `await StreamReader.ReadAsync()`
2. Write data into the `NetworkStream` using `await StreamWriter.WriteAsync()`
3. Send watchdog messages periodically

Now, when I call something like this:

```
var stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);

// reading task

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    // ...read...
}
```

The underlying `NetworkStream` gets eventually destroyed after reading has been done because `StreamReader` closes it on `Dispose()`.

The easiest way would be not closing the `StreamReader`, but AFAIK this is a very bad idea. So, how can I handle asynchronous reading and writing while keeping the socket connection open?

Comment: As a minor observation: I do a lot of socket work, and a lot of binary protocol work; I **never ever** use `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter`, because frankly they don't add much - you might want to consider just working directly off the `Stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From .NET 4.5 onwards, if you look through the constructor overloads for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, there is one (and currently only one) constructor that takes a `bool leaveOpen` parameter. Use this overload and pass `true` - then it won't feel ownership of the underlying stream.

If this isn't available on your framework version, you'll have to create a `NonClosingStream : Stream` that decorates a stream using pass-thru implementations for everything except `Close()` and `Dispose()`, which should be no-ops (well, they could assign `null` to the field that represents the wrapped stream, but nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `StreamReader` will always dispose the underling stream on its own disposal (that's why actually it **is** `IDisposable`), you do indeed have to not close it until you have no need in the network stream anymore.

So, this is very ok for the situation:

```
var stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

And when you are finish, you would close both of them, right?

```
reader.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

Comment: in .NET 4.5, both [reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx) and [writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) have "and optionally leaves the stream open." support, so it is not true that they "will always dispose the underlying stream"

Comment: @MarcGravell very well.